# Run time resolution c++ Namespace conflicts

Tags: c++

File1.h

```
// Declaration  
Class A  
{  
void Func();  
}  
//Along with some other stuff
```

---

File1.cpp

```
//Definition  
A::Func()  
{  
} 

// Along with some other stuff
```

---

File2.h

```
class A  
{  
 void Func();  
}
```

---

File2.cpp

```
// Definition  
File2::A::Func()  
{  
}
```

---

```
File3.cpp  
#include "File1.h"  
#include "File2.h"  
//   
Invokes Func()
```

---

Main1.cpp   Main2.cpp

Main1.cpp File3.cpp and File2.cpp are build together
Main1.cpp File3.cpp and File1.cpp are build together
I want to invoke `Func()` depending different linkage
But, it gives me compile time error.
How should I get around compile time error?
Is there standard way to get around above problem?

If I use namespace for File1 and File2 then I will not be able to 
invoke dynamically. Note: I can not change File1.h

Comment: You might want to include the compilation error in your question.

Comment: Can you explain more of how you hope to make use of these duplicate class definitions and "invoke dynamically"? Right now, this feels like something that isn't ever going to work as desired.

Comment: File1 and File2 are not namespaces. There is no run time resolution of namespaces. class in C++ starts as "class" and not "Class". Definition of function needs to specify the return type and so on...

Comment: if your assumption is that because the class names are the same, the appropriate class will be picked up, then that is a wrong assumption. That is not how the compiler+linker would work. You will need to provide the namespace so that the compiler knows the exact definition of the class. Like the others pointed out, please specify your intent a little more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Java (for one example), which enforces a 1:1 correspondence between classes and file names, C++ basically ignores file names completely. As such, to resolve the conflict between your two classes (both named `A`), you can use namespaces:

```
//file1.h:
class A 
    void Func();
};

//file1.cpp:
A::Func() {}

//file2.h:
namespace f2 { 
class A { 
    void Func();
};
}

// file2.cpp:

namespace f2 { 
    A::Func() {}
}

// main.cpp
#include "file1.h"
#include "file2.h"

int main() {
    A f1a;
    f2::A f2a;

    f1a.Func();  // invokes Func declared in file1.h, which is in global namespace
    f2a.Func();  // invokes Func declared in file2.h, which is in namespace f2
    return 0;
}
```

It's not clear what you mean by invoking dynamically. Dynamic invocation sounds a lot like using a polymorphic function, which would require a common base class:

```
struct base { 
    virtual void Func() = 0;
};

struct A1 : public base { 
    virtual void Func() {}
};

struct A2 : public base { 
    virtual void Func() {}
};

int main() { 
    A1 a1;
    A2 a2;
    base *b[2] = { &a1, &a2 };

    b[0]->Func(); // invokes A1::Func()
    b[1]->Func(); // invokes A2::Func()
    return 0;
}
```